# Left and Right Riemann Sum for non-continuous functions

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 , \text{ if } x \in [0,1]- \left\{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right\} \\  1 \text{ if  } x= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{cases}$$

Then are the right-hand Riemann sum and the left hand Riemann sum are both zero? i.e. $R_n = \sum_{i=1}f (\frac{i}{n})= 0 = \sum_{i=1}f \left(\frac{i-1}{n}\right) =L_n$

If we are talking about an arbitrary partition $P = \{ 0=t_0 <t_1 < \cdots < t_n=1\}$, would the right hand and left hand Riemann sum associated with $P$ still be zero? i.e.$$R= \sum_{j=1} f(t_j) \cdot \Delta t_j=0 = \sum_{j=1} f(t_{j-1}) \cdot \Delta t_j=L.$$

I think it's true, because the integral of this "almost continuous function" would be zero. Could anyone let me know if this is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: If by right and left Riemann sum you mean the limiting process where $\delta t_j$ goes to $0$ then yes, they will be equal. If instead you are talking about a particular partition of of $[0,1]$ then they would be different.

Comment: An *arbitrary* partition might contain the special point $\sqrt{2}/2.$ If it did, what are the left and right sums?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because the first part says a $n$-partition. So each "rectangle " is of length $\frac{1}{n}$. Is it correct to say that since $n$ is a natural number, it cannot contain the point $\sqrt{2}/2$? But for an arbitrary partition, we may or may not contain the point. If it did, then don't we have something like 1 and 0 for the right and left sums? Thanks!

Comment: @Toasted_Brain Just a note: If the arbitrary partition contains the point $c=\sqrt{2}/2$ then, since it must also contain the two points $0$ and $1$ to be a partition of $[0,1],$ it follows that the point $c$ will be both one of the left endpoints and one of the right endpoints of the partition, making the left and right sums both $1$ multiplied by the length of one of the intervals in the partition.

Answer (score 1):

Your right and left Riemann sum is always $0$ because there is not a partition where ${\sqrt 2\over 2}=\sup t_j \text{ or } \inf t_j$ so you are always taking the $0$. If you use the Darboux sum, the upper and lower sum always are the same value because the range of $f(x)$ is the singleton $\{1\}$ and so taking the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {1\over n} =0 $$